# Deleting old message when Discord.JS sends new message

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a music bot with DiscordJS. It sends a message again when it switches to new music. When it is too much, it causes pollution. How can I set the old message to be deleted and the new message to remain when I switch to a new song or skip a song?

[image: multiple messages on Discord]

Code:

```js
const { EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, Client } = require('discord.js');
const ms = require('ms');

/**
 * @param {Client} client 
 */

module.exports.run = async (client, player, track) => {
  function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
  }

  const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
    .addComponents(
      new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('loop')
        .setEmoji(``)
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary),

      new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('volume-')
        .setEmoji(``)
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger),

      new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('p/p')
        .setEmoji(`⏯️`)
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary),

      new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('volume+')
        .setEmoji(``)
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success),

      new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('skip')
        .setEmoji(`⏭️`)
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary),
    );

  const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setAuthor({
      name: `Now Playing`,
      iconURL: track.info.requester.displayAvatarURL(),
    })
    .setColor('Blue')
    .setDescription(
      `
      **Track**: [${track.info.title}](${track.info.uri})
`,
    )

  const channel = client.channels.cache.get(player.textChannel)
  await channel?.send({ embeds: [embed], components: [row] })
};
```

When I switch to the new song, I want the old message to be deleted. I tried removing some lines but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store an object that contains channel IDs and message IDs somewhere else in your code:

```js
let songMessages = {
  'channel-id-here':'message-id-here',
  'another-channel-id':'another-message-id',
  // etc
}
```

Instead of sending a new message at the bottom of your `run()` function, you could first check for an existing message in the current channel, and if there is one, you can delete it.

```js
// assuming you're able to access the songMessages object globally

const channel = client.channels.cache.get(player.textChannel)

if(songMessages[channel.id]) {
  let oldMessage = await channel.messages.fetch(songMessages[channel.id])
  await oldMessage.delete()
}

let message = await channel?.send({ embeds: [embed], components: [row] })
songMessages[channel.id] = message.id
```

You'll have to make sure you remove the data from the object after the bot stops playing music as well.